# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError error with jawt.lib linkeage on 32-bit Window7/8 OS

Tags: java, c++, windows

I try to compile javaaccessbridge.dll.
I compile the project in 64 bit os on x86 configuration with VS2015.
The library path set in

**Configure-linker-Input-Additional Dependacy**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\lib\jawt.lib"
```

This dll work fine in 64 bit OS Window 7/8 with JRE 32/64.

Now its gives below exception in 32-bit OS window 7/8.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Rovet.Sen\Des
ktop\POC\U\WindowsAccessBridge-32.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

JRE 6,7,8 already install in 32 bit OS.

Can any one help me which dependency missing by me in 32-bit OS window 7/8?

THanks

Comment: It is not throw exception while remove "jawt.lib" from linker.

Comment: I am not using any 64-dll.

Comment: Is it mean, x86 configuration and 64 bit OS compiled exe not run on 32-bit OS?

Comment: I got the solution I need to call system.loadlibrary("jawt") and then i call my native library.It works in window7 32 bit OS with any JRE

Comment: The above same soluction is not working in window8 32 bit os. Can you help me why it occur?